# High CPU utilization when doing thousands of inserts with Hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, transactions

We have recently implemented DB binding using Hibernate with EntityManager (no Spring) to write records to a database.  To make things simple, I will only discuss the variation of the process that only does inserts.  (Another, very similar, process updates an existing record once to set a status, but otherwise, just inserts a bunch of records.)

This process can insert as many as 10,000 records per transaction, though the average is less than that, probably by at least half.  We might have a few instances of this process running in different threads at the same time under the same JVM.

We had a production issue where the service the process was running under was pegging out all 24 cores on the machine.  (They added 12 just to try to accommodate this.)  We have narrowed this high utilization down to Hibernate.

I have spent days researching and can not find anything that might improve our performance, except to use hibernate.jdbc.batch_size along with hibernate.order_inserts.  Unfortunately, we are using IDENTITY as our generation strategy, so Hibernate can/will not batch those inserts.

I've spent days researching and have not found any other performance tip when doing large numbers of inserts.  (I've seen many tips regarding reads, updates, and deletes, but very few for inserts.)

We have a root JobPO object.  We simply call merge on that and all the inserts are handled via the cascade annotations.  We need to do this in a single transaction.

We have only 8 different tables that we are inserting into, but the hierarchy of records is a bit complicated.

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Object dataHierarchyRoot) {
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    final EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

    try {
        transaction.begin();

        // This single call may result in inserting up to 10K records
        entityManager.merge(dataHierarchyRoot);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        // error handling redacted for brevity
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

We create the EntityManagerFactory only once.

Any ideas?

Additional notes:

- No one has complained about the process using too much memory
- For the variation of the process that is doing only inserts, we could just use "persist" instead of "merge".  We are sharing the code, so we do a merge.  I tried switching to persist with no discernible improvement.
- We do have annotations that result in bi-directional Cascade on a few of the fields.  I tried removing these, but being new to Hibernate, couldn't get it to save properly.  From what I understand, though, it doesn't seem as if this would cause performance degradation for inserts.  I am not using explicit "inverse" settings, since that seems to not matter for inserts, either.  I am a little shaky on both these areas, though.  Is there room for improvement in this area?
- We ran SQL Profiler during a single transaction.  Nothing seemed amiss and I did not spot room for improvement.  (There were a large number of exec sp_prepexec statements, approximately the same number as the number of records that were inserted.  That was all that was reported.)
- The code exhibiting this behavior in production was making an explicit call to entityManager.flush() just before the commit().  I removed that code in my local environment.  It did not make a noticeable improvement, but I won't add it back, because there is no reason for us to call flush().

Comment: You mention Hibernate pegs all 24 cores in a machine, How long does it take to complete the insert? a few seconds or a lot more? If all 24 cores are pegged that would mean you are spawning a lot of threads in your business logic. Could you explain more about your multi-threading logic in doing the insert?

Comment: For 9K, it takes roughly 2 minutes.  The DBAs state that the database is tuned as well as it can be.  There can be multiple instances of the process running in different threads calling the code I included above for different objects.  These threads share no objects except the EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: I have had experience with Hibernate inserting a tree structure containing 10000 records in less than a second. There is definitely some optimization that needs to be done. Please profile your code to find and fix the inefficient parts. You can use Yourkit for this purpose.

Comment: Were you doing this within a single transaction?  Did you have the batch_size option > 1?  We had another developer profile with Yourkit during initial development phase and reported there were no "hot spots" within the Hibernate piece.  I will give it another go.  I don't have high hopes.  Other than the suggestion below, I do not know what else we could do from a code standpoint.  Note that the call to merge(), prior to commit takes up at least half the execution time.  I do not know at this time if it is the merge() or the commit() or both that is utilizing so much CPU.

Comment: I prefer not to rely on Hibernate's merge since it will cause performance issues as the whole process is out of your control.
Could you separate the process of loading the data and doing a manual merge?. This allows you to make optimizations on each part separately.
The loading can be accomplished using HQL. Depending on how complex your model is the merging code might be trivial or complex.

Comment: I possibly could. One version of our process uses this code such that the "root" object is updated (update in the DB), but all other objects result in an insert in the DB. Regarding separating "loading the data" and doing manual merge, we do load the root object first. Then I update it, so I thought I have to do a merge. My only options are "merge" or "persist".  I could do a merge on the root object without cascading. Then do persist on the remaining. Is that what you meant? The merge/persist would have be within the same transaction, unless I implement a psuedo-transaction -  suggested below

Comment: I'd have to run a profiler to determine if this makes a difference. We have a monolithic code base, so might take a while to set up. For now, we have a short-term solution to cap the number of concurrent threads to "smooth out" the load over time. We hope this will be adequate for now. Since we didn't easily find a way to improve this, I am not sure if I'll be allowed to spend more time on this, until/unless we have further production issues in the future (which our production team says we will at some point). If/when I find a way to improve performance I will definitely make note if it here.

Comment: In your case there is only one way to update an object i.e., through the root node. This makes sense if you are doing an action like import where the user is fine with the response time, because it is expected. If your "expectation" is that updates should not take 2 minutes, then there is obviously scope for improvement. For example, if only a few objects are changed and you have information on what those objects are, then a separate API can be created to make that update. So you are trading off a more verbose API to get better performance.

Comment: This is a very basic load scenario.  We are loading data from a file and importing the data as a tree structure to a DB.  There is no user interaction at all.

Comment: I posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 5):

If you open and close a Session for every object you are about to save, then for 10k objects you are practically opening and closing 10k Sessions, flushing 10k times and going to the database for 10k round-trips.

You should at least [batch multiple entities](http://vladmihalcea.com/scheduled-jobs-best-practices/) together:

```
for (Object entity: entities) {    
    if(entity.getId() == null) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    } else {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }   
    if ((i % batchSize) == 0) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.clear();          
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
}
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

In this example you are practically using one database connection, so even if you use connection pooling you won't have to acquire/release 10k DB connections. The Session is cleared after the `batchSize` threshold is reached, therefore reducing the JVM garbage collection.

If you store 10k entities in a session and commit the transaction at once you will run into the following issues:

- the database will hold locks for a longer period of time and will create huge undo transaction logs (in case your database uses MVCC)
- the entities won't be garbage collected, as they are still attached to the Hibernate Session

Comment: For the 10K records, we have one transaction and one session.  Saving the root Job record is what results in the 10K records being inserted.  In the sample code I provided, that single call to merge(object) is what will result in up to 10K records being inserted.  We need to save all these records in a single transaction.  (We could do it without a transaction, but not without jumping through hoops.  They should all be inserted or none.  That is what transactions are for.)

Comment: Ideally yes, but in reality adding a huge batch takes a lot of resources. I wonder of you really can't split those 10k into smaller batches.

Comment: Thanks.  We are saving basically a tree structure, so the records all have a link, directly or indirectly, to the root object.  To update our code to insert these in separate batches, which I consider to be a hack, would complicate the code/testing a lot.

Comment: Also, if that is the solution, I would say Hibernate is not enterprise-ready, despite its wide usage.  Our home-grown version we normally use could handle this # in a single transaction with no issue.    If it turns out this is the only solution within Hibernate, we may consider enhancing our home grown solution instead.  (We switched to Hibernate because our home grown solution can't currently handle BigInt as the primary key.)

Comment: Even though this is not a neat solution, I will take this option (and any others that may be recommended) to our architects for review.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You should avoid opening and closing connections on each update because it hurts performance. Instead, You could configure your persistence provider to use batch processing and set a reasonable number, and then perform a batch update.

```
<persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@***"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>   
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

This allows sending multiple update queries in a single command to the database when your are updating/inserting into a loop (it is transparent to you).

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Employee employee = new Employee(.....);
    session.save(employee);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

References: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Comment: As mentioned in my post, we can not use the batch_size property because we use GenerationType.IDENTITY generation strategy for our primary keys.  Changing our strategy now is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or at least a way to greatly decrease CPU usage) was to switch from merge to persist.  I had mentioned in my post that I had tried switching to persist with no discernible difference.

I have subsequently found a better way to profile heavy loads and with that was able to show the improvement.  Switching from persist to merge for the particular load I was running reduced average CPU percentage from 16 to 5.

We do not need to merge.  For the permanent fix, we need to rework the code a little to be able to use the same EntityManager for loading the root object and then persisting it (which will then cascade the full "tree" structure).  This way, our object doesn't become detached and we don't need to use merge.

Thanks to ddalton for pointing in that direction.